# XML Parsing issue in Flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex, e4x

I have an XML with more than 10,000 lines,when i am parsing that xml using URLLoader class.i am unable to trace the entire xml.While tracing i am getting xml from the middle.can anyone suggest me how to parse the xml document.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: 10,000 lines of XML is too much of data - try to break it down into smaller segments before loading to flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flex Builder 3, the console is limited to 80,000 characters by default.

To change, or remove this limit look at the following Preferences Page...

Preferences > Run/Debug > Console

Answer (score 0):

I think the console is limited on how many lines it can display. I solved this by creating a viewstack, putting all of my application in one view, and a big text area in another view. Then I have a button that will take me to that text area view and when it does it populates the text area with the XML. Then I can see it all. I have not come across any limit to the number of lines this can handle.

Comment: Thanks it might some console problem